# text input c# compare value and restriction

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        int v1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        int v2 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text);
        int v3 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox3.Text);
        int v4 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox4.Text);
        int v5 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox5.Text);
        int v6 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
        int v7 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox7.Text);
        int v8 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox8.Text);
        int v9 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox9.Text);
        int v10 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox10.Text);

        int n11 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox11.Text);
        int n12 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox12.Text);
        int n13 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox13.Text);
        int n14 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox14.Text);
        int n15 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox15.Text);
        int n16 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox16.Text);
        int n17 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox17.Text);
        int n18 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox18.Text);
        int n19 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox19.Text);
        int n20 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox20.Text);




        List<int> list = new List<int>() { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9 ,v10  };
        List<int> list2 = new List<int>() { n11, n12, n13, n14, n15, n16, n17, n18, n19, n20 };
        list = list.OrderBy(o => o).ToList();
        list2 = list2.OrderBy(o => o).ToList();
        list2.SequenceEqual(list);


}
```

hi evryone, this is the second part of this project i need help figuring out how to compare values ( numbers ) in list vs list2, 
Example if "list" contain number 5 and "list2" also contain number 5, i need a true if not false , the order is not important,Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself already?

Comment: here is a freebee for the easiest part `textBox1.MaxLength = 2;` the rest you can google ..there are tons of examples online do a google search on `C# char.IsDigit` function

Comment: @Scottlove I posted an answer that will work for you. there are many ways that you can call the method that I have written for you. You need to test out the scenario in regards to if someone copies and pastes a value into the textbox then you could add an [Control.Leave Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.leave.aspx) if the method returns false show a message and set focus back to that textbox

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to validate the input

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int value = 100 ;

     if ( !int.TryParse ( textBox1.Text, out value ) || value > 99 || value < -99 )
     {
         textBox1.TextChanged -= textBox1_TextChanged;
         textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
         textBox1.TextChanged += textBox1_TextChanged;
     }
}
```

Comment: I think that the `char.IsDigit` function would work best something like this 
`e.Handled = !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsControl(e.KeyChar);`

Comment: @MethodMan are you suore you allways get one char variation every time the handle fired ?
What if i copy and paste text inside the textbox ?

Comment: why check if value > 99 when all you have to do at design time is set the max length of that field once .. also I have a better working method which I use all the time I will post it as answer

Comment: i added a screen shot of the form so you guys understand my goal better , simply avoid the user entering more than 2 digit and comparing the result with a check button.

Comment: I don't know any integer with more than two digit that are smaller than 100.
But i know some version of .Net that does not support max length on winform (if my memory does not trick me .NetCF does not support it)
Finally consider -99 that have less than two digit but more than two symbol.

Comment: @Skary I posted a more scalable version check it out if you like

Answer (score 0):

write your own method like this

```
public static bool isNumeric(string val, System.Globalization.NumberStyles NumberStyle)
{
    Int32 result;
    return Int32.TryParse(val, NumberStyle,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result);
}
```

> Here is how you would call it

```
var _isNumeric = isNumeric("9.", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);//test like this returns false
```

in your case replace the string with the textBox1.Text value

```
var _isNumeric = isNumeric(textBox1.Text, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Integer);
```